# Splitting string does not work

Tags: java, string

I am having issues with the string splitting.

Here is my code

```
 Document doc = null;
    String name = "MasterEjzz";


    try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://oc.tc/forums").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {

            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Seems like something went wrong! Are you connected to the internet?");
    }

    Elements content = doc.getElementsByClass("topic");
   Elements post = content.select("div");
   for (Element a : content.select("div")){
       Elements href = a.select("a");
       for (Element link : href){
           String links = link.attr("abs:href");
           String[] b = links.split("https");
           System.out.print(links);
           //System.out.print(b.toString());
```

I want to split the string links by the word https, but when I do, b[0] returns nothing and b[1] returns an OutOfBounds exception. Here is what the string links returns

```
https://oc.tc/forums/topics/523b038faf7fb046f700255dhttps://oc.tc/tjandralalahttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b2131af7fb0557a002882https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b2131af7fb0557a002882https://oc.tc/forums/topics/51d1cb3cba6087dd20003a35https://oc.tc/ENSIONMANhttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b2117af7fb030690027f7https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b2117af7fb030690027f7https://oc.tc/forums/topics/519c1971a87858d604004c3ahttps://oc.tc/MadCreeper77https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b20bdaf7fb010920026a2https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b20bdaf7fb010920026a2https://oc.tc/forums/topics/51ff8a7daf7fb0053a001fe0https://oc.tc/MadCreeper77https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1f8aaf7fb001bf002756https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1f8aaf7fb001bf002756https://oc.tc/forums/topics/5237d369af7fb0b81600038dhttps://oc.tc/zacharycraft777https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1f72af7fb033ab00259fhttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1f72af7fb033ab00259fhttps://oc.tc/forums/topics/523a5de9af7fb062c7001cf1https://oc.tc/lonelyhornethttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1de7af7fb074e0002416https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1de7af7fb074e0002416https://oc.tc/forums/topics/5238ff9aaf7fb001bf0000cahttps://oc.tc/lonelyhornethttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1d2baf7fb02dbc0025echttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1d2baf7fb02dbc0025echttps://oc.tc/forums/topics/5235f53baf7fb04c5100170ehttps://oc.tc/Kevinthedude2000https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1b69af7fb01783002714https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1b69af7fb01783002714https://oc.tc/forums/topics/522bcb94af7fb05fdc000ec8https://oc.tc/skippy369https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b19cfaf7fb06378002384https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b19cfaf7fb06378002384https://oc.tc/forums/topics/523aebe7af7fb0dafa0024d7https://oc.tc/MrAmazing1337https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1867af7fb01dde0028e6https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1867af7fb01dde0028e6https://oc.tc/forums/topics/523b0f8caf7fb0a8240022e2https://oc.tc/Eulenspielerhttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b185daf7fb0dafa002822https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b185daf7fb0dafa002822https://oc.tc/forums/topics/5239058daf7fb06708000191https://oc.tc/ENSIONMANhttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1787af7fb01092002585https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1787af7fb01092002585https://oc.tc/forums/topics/52388f49af7fb0413f000e7dhttps://oc.tc/zacharycraft777https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1701af7fb02bf300283chttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1701af7fb02bf300283chttps://oc.tc/forums/topics/5237b7d7af7fb0440f0001b9https://oc.tc/ENSIONMANhttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b14a8af7fb0ccc5002285https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b14a8af7fb0ccc5002285https://oc.tc/forums/topics/5237f69daf7fb040dc0006d1https://oc.tc/ENSIONMANhttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b141eaf7fb0c73b002647https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b141eaf7fb0c73b002647https://oc.tc/forums/topics/51bd5e6eba6087d4e60020efhttps://oc.tc/iLiftinghttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1413af7fb0ccc5002270https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1413af7fb0ccc5002270https://oc.tc/forums/topics/51de6b74af7fb0a091004b40https://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b138eaf7fb0fbf9002313https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b138eaf7fb0fbf9002313https://oc.tc/forums/topics/5196b74ca87858886a003a43https://oc.tc/Shadowbladzhttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1201af7fb056ab002297https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b1201af7fb056ab002297https://oc.tc/forums/topics/523b0f4daf7fb01dde002803https://oc.tc/1234notty1234https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b0f4daf7fb01dde002802https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b0f4daf7fb01dde002802https://oc.tc/forums/topics/52281f11af7fb0e4ed00423dhttps://oc.tc/Eldnickhttps://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b0f1caf7fb046f7002681https://oc.tc/forums/posts/523b0f1caf7fb046f7002681
```

Comment: @allprog he printed links, and claimed that it's what he put at the end of his post.

Comment: The split itself works fine. The string must be empty or something different from whats posted

Comment: The first one should be empty, there's an empty string before the first `https`. And [that string splits as it should](https://ideone.com/uRMmj4) (thus `links` is probably not what you say it is), give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows the results you're talking about.

Comment: Yeah, you need to give us something reproducable. I ran this: `String links = "your big string"; System.out.println(System.out.println(links.split("https").length));` and got 81.

Comment: Ok, I missed that but if that's true, then the split should return the sliced string. `b[0] is nothing` means the original string was empty but not null since that would have thrown an exception.

Comment: @allprog first string as empty is correct. Since links starts with the token in question. What makes no sense it the outofboundsexception

Comment: @Cruncher yeah, I should stop for today. But as the array is only 1 long and there is a single empty item in it, this can mean either an empty input or a single `https` token. Anything else would produce other output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to test your problem:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "https://oc.tc/forums/topics/523b038faf7fb046f700255dhttps://oc.tc/tjandralala";
        String[] split = str.split("https");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
    }
}
```

And I got the following output: `[, ://oc.tc/forums/topics/523b038faf7fb046f700255d, ://oc.tc/tjandralala]`

The first element isn't nothing. It's the [empty string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string) (λ). Basically java treats your sting as if it looks like `λhttps://oc.tc/forums/topics/523b038faf7fb046f700255d`. So the first split is the empty string and then s://...

If you need to include the https try using StringUtils.

Comment: This doesn't explain the outofboundsexception

Comment: Sure doesn't. I couldn't reproduce it. He'd have to provide an SSCCE that produces it.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens method

```
String https = "https://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/Haxasauroushttps://oc.tc/Haxasaurous";

String[] strArr = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens(
            https, "https");
for(String str:strArr) {
sysout(str);
}
```

Comment: What is the first arg in the splitByWholeSeparator mean?

Comment: That is the source string you want to split

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: I get an error saying that splitByWhole... is undefined for StringUtils. I imported com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.StringUtils. Is this correct?

Comment: No. Please import from commons lang. 
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

Comment: That does not work for some reason. It says that it can't find that.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you haven't checked if the call to `.attr()` returns `null` or `""`?

```
   String links = link.attr("abs:href");
   if (links != null && !links.equals("")) { 
       String[] b = links.split("https");

       for (String path : b) {
          if (!path.equals(""))
              System.out.println(link);
       }
   }
```

When you split `"abcdabceabcf"` by `"abc"` you get the array `["", "d", "e", "f"]`.

Answer (score 0):

When run against the host address shown in the question, the `JSoup` returned `links` as

```
https://oc.tc/forums/topics/523b25afaf7fb08f4b002479
```

I.e. there is only 1 element when split using "https"

Solution: Either check the `length` of the array before attempting to access a particular element or iterate through the elements returned.